# Cakephp 2.1 beforeSave not working

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.1, before-save

I have a User Model, a UsersController and an AccountController which **uses** the User Model (the account controller is used when an account is created, login, logout).

Everything works fine, except the beforeSave function in AccountController. I'm trying to use beforeSave to hash my password but it doesn't work (the password is saved un-hashed in the database).

```
public function beforeSave() {
    parent::beforeSave();   

    if (isset($this->request->data['User']['password'])) {
        $this->request->data['User']['password'] = sha1($this->request->data['User']['password']);
    }

    return true;
}
```

A few notes:

- I use "sha1" to hash the password because I'm converting an old system to CakePHP (the old system used sha1 to hash the passwords)
- Even if I `return false;` the save function is still executed (which I thought should not be the case
- calling `debug($this->request->data)` gives me nothing
- I added the same beforeSave function in my UsersController but it didn't work as well

I think in my case **beforeSave** is not being called, I just can't figure out why.

---

**Solved:**
The beforeSave function has to go inside the model, this is my beforeSave function now:

```
public function beforeSave($options = array()) {
        parent::beforeSave();
        $this->data['User']['password'] = sha1($this->data['User']['password']);
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: Not so relevant to your question... But do you really want to hash your password this way? Why don't you use `AuthComponent::password($this->request->data['User']['password'])` for that? That makes sure you use your apps configured hashing strategy for the passwords, and prevents trouble if you'd ever decide to switch to another hashing method

Comment: Ah ok, so I can change the hashing method in a config file so that `sha1()` is being used?

Comment: [Cookbook on AuthComponent::password](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html#hashing-passwords)
And, yeah, you should be able to configure that somewhere, probably core.php or something (I'm not sure where that option is in 2.1)

Comment: Thank you! I will definitely look into this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

beforeSave is a [Model callback](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/callback-methods.html), so define it in your Model(s).

Comment: Oh wow, yeah that is wrong. I implemented it in my Model but its still not hashing the password. But if I `return false;` at least the data is not saved.